# Replacing NA with string if string found on other variable

Tags: r, string, for-loop

I have a DF that contains sources from the traffic of a webpage. the column `source` contains the detailed source, while `global_sources` is a handmade categorization that doesn't change. What I'm trying to do is, if `global_sources` is NA, string detect the unique values of `global_sources` in `source` and replace NA with the string that matched.

#### What the DF lookslike:

```
source <- c('facebook / cpc', 'googletest', 'adwords.google', 'organic', 'source / referral', 'google / source', 'facebook / test')
global_sources <- c('facebook', 'google', NA, 'organic', 'referral', NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(source, global_sources)
df
```

| source | global_sources |
| --- | --- |
| facebook /cpc | facebook |
| googletest | google |
| adwords.google | NA |
| organic | organic |
| source / referral | referral |
| google / referral | google |
| facebook / test | NA |

#### What I currently have:

```
df$global_sources <- ifelse(is.na(df$global_sources),
                            ifelse(str_detect(df$source, 'facebook'), 'facebook', NA), df$global_sources)

df
```

| source | global_sources |
| --- | --- |
| facebook /cpc | facebook |
| googletest | google |
| adwords.google | NA |
| organic | organic |
| source / referral | referral |
| google / referral | NA |
| facebook / test | facebook |

Up to this point the code only detects and replaces NA values in `global_sources` if the string in sources matches 'facebook', otherwise it leaves it as NA. The problem is that I need to do it for all the unique categories in `global_sources`. I tried doing it with another `ifelse`, but there are so many categories that it ends up in something super unefficent and hard to read.

#### Expected outcome:

I'm trying to do a `for loop` but I haven't been able to do anything that works. The intended outcome is:

| source | global_sources |
| --- | --- |
| facebook /cpc | facebook |
| googletest | google |
| adwords.google | google |
| organic | organic |
| source / referral | referral |
| google / referral | google |
| facebook / test | facebook |

Note that some values in source have more than one category (like google / referral) but in those cases the last priority is matching with referral.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a single application of `str_detect()` when combined with a matching function. This assumes that when `NA` is encountered there will be exactly 1 match in `global_sources`. If that's not true, you'll probably need something more complex.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(source = c('facebook / cpc', 'googletest', 'adwords.google', 'organic', 'source / referral', 'google / source', 'facebook / test'), 
                 global_sources = c('facebook', 'google', NA, 'organic', 'referral', NA, NA))

# pull out unique options for global_sources
g <- unique(na.omit(df$global_sources))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(global_sources = if_else(
    is.na(global_sources),
    g[str_detect(source, g)],
    global_sources
  )) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>   source            global_sources
#>   <chr>             <chr>         
#> 1 facebook / cpc    facebook      
#> 2 googletest        google        
#> 3 adwords.google    google        
#> 4 organic           organic       
#> 5 source / referral referral      
#> 6 google / source   google        
#> 7 facebook / test   facebook
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This works for the scope of your example, but you'll have to tinker the `regex` for more use cases. If there's some kind of hierarchy, this won't work, but we'll need more information:

```
df %>% mutate(global_sources = if_else(is.na(global_sources), 
              str_extract(source, 'facebook|google') , global_sources))

# A tibble: 7 × 2
# source            global_sources
# <chr>             <chr>         
# 1 facebook / cpc    facebook      
# 2 googletest        google        
# 3 adwords.google    google        
# 4 organic           organic       
# 5 source / referral referral      
# 6 google / source   google        
# 7 facebook / test   facebook
```